# Wireless device is enabled but no network list is shown

Tags: networking, wireless, drivers, network-manager, realtek

The wireless device is shown and it is enabled on Network Manager but no networks are displayed.

This happens often and with no visible reason.

When I turn off the computer, unplug the energy cable, count to ten, reconnect the energy cable and turn on the computer again, the wireless network list becomes available again. If I don't disconnect the energy cable this workaround doesn't work.

This often happened a while ago. My machine does not have a shortcut key to enable / disable the wireless network, I didn't have the "disconnect energy cable" workaround yet, so the solution was restart to the Windows (dual boot), enable the wireless network on the control panel and back to Ubuntu.

How can I have my wireless network working again with out neither of this weird workarounds?

```
########## wireless info START ##########

Report from: 01 Oct 2015 15:33 BRT -0300

Booted last: 01 Oct 2015 12:39 BRT -0300

Script from: 27 Sep 2015 00:34 UTC +0000

##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 15.04
Release:    15.04
Codename:   vivid

##### kernel ############################

Linux 3.19.0-30-generic #33-Ubuntu SMP Mon Sep 21 20:58:04 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, quiet, splash, nomdmonddf, nomdmonisw

##### desktop ###########################

Ubuntu

##### lspci #############################

03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723AE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:8723]
    Subsystem: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device [10ec:0726]
    Kernel driver in use: rtl8723ae

04:00.2 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 0a)
    Subsystem: CLEVO/KAPOK Computer Device [1558:3537]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169

##### lsusb #############################

Bus 004 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 8087:8008 Intel Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:8723 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 22b8:2e62 Motorola PCS 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 1a81:1004 Holtek Semiconductor, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 147e:1002 Upek Biometric Touchchip/Touchstrip Fingerprint Sensor
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

##### rfkill ############################

0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

##### lsmod #############################

mxm_wmi                16384  0 
rtl8723ae              86016  0 
btcoexist              53248  1 rtl8723ae
rtl8723_common         24576  1 rtl8723ae
rtl_pci                28672  1 rtl8723ae
rtlwifi                77824  2 rtl_pci,rtl8723ae
mac80211              724992  2 rtl_pci,rtlwifi
cfg80211              540672  2 mac80211,rtlwifi
wmi                    20480  1 mxm_wmi

##### interfaces ########################

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

##### ifconfig ##########################

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'eth0' [IF]>  
          inet addr:192.168.7.61  Bcast:192.168.7.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::<IP6 'eth0' [IF]>/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:29151 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:16273 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:15567099 (15.5 MB)  TX bytes:2460199 (2.4 MB)

virbr0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'virbr0' [IF]>  
          inet addr:192.168.122.1  Bcast:192.168.122.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

virbr0-nic Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'virbr0' [IF]>  
          BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:500 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'wlan0' [IF]>  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

##### iwconfig ##########################

virbr0-nic  no wireless extensions.

eth0      no wireless extensions.

virbr0    no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr=2347 B   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off


##### route #############################

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.7.1     0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 eth0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 eth0
192.168.7.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 eth0
192.168.122.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 virbr0

##### resolv.conf #######################

nameserver 127.0.1.1

##### network managers ##################

Installed:

    NetworkManager

Running:

root       999     1  0 12:39 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon

##### NetworkManager info ###############

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         eth0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         r8169
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 2.3LK-NAPI
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'eth0' [IF]>
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
GENERAL.REASON:                         0 (No reason given)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.3/0000:04:00.2/net/eth0
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       eth0
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     Conexão cabeada 1
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       894d0e08-0474-4b2d-900b-ad9333880081
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/0
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            yes
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     100 Mb/s
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/{1}
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[1]:   894d0e08-0474-4b2d-900b-ad9333880081 | Conexão cabeada 1
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               on
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         ip = 192.168.7.61/24, gw = 192.168.7.1
IP4.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 169.254.0.0/16, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 1000
IP4.DNS[1]:                             192.168.7.1
DHCP4.OPTION[1]:                        requested_ntp_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[2]:                        requested_domain_search = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[3]:                        requested_broadcast_address = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[4]:                        requested_domain_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[5]:                        requested_rfc3442_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[6]:                        requested_time_offset = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[7]:                        expiry = 1443713945
DHCP4.OPTION[8]:                        requested_wpad = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[9]:                        next_server = 0.0.0.0
DHCP4.OPTION[10]:                       requested_netbios_scope = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[11]:                       requested_interface_mtu = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[12]:                       requested_subnet_mask = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[13]:                       dhcp_lease_time = 4294967295
DHCP4.OPTION[14]:                       ip_address = 192.168.7.61
DHCP4.OPTION[15]:                       subnet_mask = 255.255.255.0
DHCP4.OPTION[16]:                       requested_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[17]:                       routers = 192.168.7.1
DHCP4.OPTION[18]:                       broadcast_address = 192.168.7.255
DHCP4.OPTION[19]:                       domain_name_servers = 192.168.7.1
DHCP4.OPTION[20]:                       requested_domain_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[21]:                       requested_netbios_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[22]:                       requested_routers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[23]:                       requested_ms_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[24]:                       dhcp_message_type = 5
DHCP4.OPTION[25]:                       requested_host_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[26]:                       network_number = 192.168.7.0
DHCP4.OPTION[27]:                       dhcp_server_identifier = 192.168.7.1
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         ip = fe80::<IP6 'eth0' [IF]>/64, gw = ::

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         wlan0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           wifi
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        RTL8723AE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         rtl8723ae
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 3.19.0-30-generic
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               N/A
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'wlan0' [IF]>
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          30 (disconnected)
GENERAL.REASON:                         42 (The supplicant is now available)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.2/0000:03:00.0/net/wlan0
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     --
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       --
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       --
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            no
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     unknown
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: 
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WEP:                    yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WPA:                    yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WPA2:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.TKIP:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.CCMP:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.AP:                     yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.ADHOC:                  yes

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         virbr0-nic
GENERAL.TYPE:                           tap
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         --
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        --
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 1.6
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'virbr0' [IF]>
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          10 (unmanaged)
GENERAL.REASON:                         0 (No reason given)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/virtual/net/virbr0-nic
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       virbr0-nic
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     no
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     --
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       --
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       --
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            yes
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     unknown
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: 

SSID  BSSID  MODE  CHAN  FREQ  RATE  SIGNAL  BARS  SECURITY  ACTIVE  * 

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true
WimaxEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager.conf ###############

[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=false

##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Atlantis]] (600 root)
[connection] id=Atlantis | type=wifi
[wifi] ssid=Atlantis | mac-address=<MAC 'wlan0' [IF]>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

##### iw reg get ########################

Region: America/Sao_Paulo (based on set time zone)

country 00: DFS-UNSET
    (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (N/A, 20), (N/A)
    (2457 - 2482 @ 40), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-IR
    (2474 - 2494 @ 20), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-OFDM, NO-IR
    (5170 - 5250 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-IR
    (5250 - 5330 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS, NO-IR
    (5490 - 5730 @ 160), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS, NO-IR
    (5735 - 5835 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-IR
    (57240 - 63720 @ 2160), (N/A, 0), (N/A)

##### iwlist channels ###################

virbr0-nic  no frequency information.

eth0      no frequency information.

virbr0    no frequency information.

lo        no frequency information.

wlan0     13 channels in total; available frequencies :
          Channel 01 : 2.412 GHz
          Channel 02 : 2.417 GHz
          Channel 03 : 2.422 GHz
          Channel 04 : 2.427 GHz
          Channel 05 : 2.432 GHz
          Channel 06 : 2.437 GHz
          Channel 07 : 2.442 GHz
          Channel 08 : 2.447 GHz
          Channel 09 : 2.452 GHz
          Channel 10 : 2.457 GHz
          Channel 11 : 2.462 GHz
          Channel 12 : 2.467 GHz
          Channel 13 : 2.472 GHz

##### iwlist scan #######################

virbr0-nic  Interface doesn't support scanning.

eth0      Interface doesn't support scanning.

virbr0    Interface doesn't support scanning.

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

wlan0     No scan results

##### module infos ######################

[rtl8723ae]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.19.0-30-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rtlwifi/rtl8723ae/rtl8723ae.ko
firmware:       rtlwifi/rtl8723efw.bin
description:    Realtek 8723E 802.11n PCI wireless
license:        GPL
author:         Realtek WlanFAE <wlanfae@realtek.com>
author:         lizhaoming  <chaoming_li@realsil.com.cn>
srcversion:     E157B5085A0F66FF49B6BCD
depends:        rtlwifi,rtl8723-common,rtl_pci,btcoexist
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.19.0-30-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        09:1D:B2:76:17:3D:83:37:42:E9:6A:C8:70:59:1A:DB:9B:CC:DA:53
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
parm:           swenc:Set to 1 for software crypto (default 0)
 (bool)
parm:           ips:Set to 0 to not use link power save (default 1)
 (bool)
parm:           swlps:Set to 1 to use SW control power save (default 0)
 (bool)
parm:           fwlps:Set to 1 to use FW control power save (default 1)
 (bool)
parm:           debug:Set debug level (0-5) (default 0) (int)
parm:           disable_watchdog:Set to 1 to disable the watchdog (default 0)
 (bool)

[rtl8723_common]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.19.0-30-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rtlwifi/rtl8723com/rtl8723-common.ko
description:    Realtek RTL8723AE/RTL8723BE 802.11n PCI wireless common routines
license:        GPL
author:         Larry Finger    <Larry.Finger@lwfinger.net>
author:         Realtek WlanFAE <wlanfae@realtek.com>
srcversion:     251C540A2D3AD38CCA85ED9
depends:        
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.19.0-30-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        09:1D:B2:76:17:3D:83:37:42:E9:6A:C8:70:59:1A:DB:9B:CC:DA:53
sig_hashalgo:   sha512

[rtl_pci]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.19.0-30-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rtlwifi/rtl_pci.ko
description:    PCI basic driver for rtlwifi
license:        GPL
author:         Larry Finger    <Larry.FInger@lwfinger.net>
author:         Realtek WlanFAE <wlanfae@realtek.com>
author:         lizhaoming  <chaoming_li@realsil.com.cn>
srcversion:     A25DC6D8C53D55DA133BC49
depends:        mac80211,rtlwifi
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.19.0-30-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        09:1D:B2:76:17:3D:83:37:42:E9:6A:C8:70:59:1A:DB:9B:CC:DA:53
sig_hashalgo:   sha512

[rtlwifi]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.19.0-30-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rtlwifi/rtlwifi.ko
description:    Realtek 802.11n PCI wireless core
license:        GPL
author:         Larry Finger    <Larry.FInger@lwfinger.net>
author:         Realtek WlanFAE <wlanfae@realtek.com>
author:         lizhaoming  <chaoming_li@realsil.com.cn>
srcversion:     35016235A31CEB1854418E1
depends:        mac80211,cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.19.0-30-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        09:1D:B2:76:17:3D:83:37:42:E9:6A:C8:70:59:1A:DB:9B:CC:DA:53
sig_hashalgo:   sha512

[mac80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.19.0-30-generic/kernel/net/mac80211/mac80211.ko
license:        GPL
description:    IEEE 802.11 subsystem
srcversion:     6AE775D26377F997426A49D
depends:        cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.19.0-30-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        09:1D:B2:76:17:3D:83:37:42:E9:6A:C8:70:59:1A:DB:9B:CC:DA:53
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
parm:           minstrel_vht_only:Use only VHT rates when VHT is supported by sta. (bool)
parm:           max_nullfunc_tries:Maximum nullfunc tx tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           max_probe_tries:Maximum probe tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           beacon_loss_count:Number of beacon intervals before we decide beacon was lost. (int)
parm:           probe_wait_ms:Maximum time(ms) to wait for probe response before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           ieee80211_default_rc_algo:Default rate control algorithm for mac80211 to use (charp)

[cfg80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.19.0-30-generic/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
description:    wireless configuration support
license:        GPL
author:         Johannes Berg
srcversion:     F28307769349A31F4B24FC2
depends:        
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.19.0-30-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        09:1D:B2:76:17:3D:83:37:42:E9:6A:C8:70:59:1A:DB:9B:CC:DA:53
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
parm:           ieee80211_regdom:IEEE 802.11 regulatory domain code (charp)
parm:           cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz:Disable 40MHz support in the 2.4GHz band (bool)

##### module parameters #################

[rtl8723ae]
debug: 0
disable_watchdog: N
fwlps: Y
ips: Y
swenc: N
swlps: N

[mac80211]
beacon_loss_count: 7
ieee80211_default_rc_algo: minstrel_ht
max_nullfunc_tries: 2
max_probe_tries: 5
minstrel_vht_only: Y
probe_wait_ms: 500

[cfg80211]
cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz: N
ieee80211_regdom: 00

##### /etc/modules ######################

##### modprobe options ##################

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist i2c_i801
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/intel-microcode-blacklist.conf]
blacklist microcode

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211

[/etc/modprobe.d/mlx4.conf]
softdep mlx4_core post: mlx4_en

[/etc/modprobe.d/qemu-system-x86.conf]
options kvm_intel nested=1

##### rc.local ##########################

exit 0

##### pm-utils ##########################

##### udev rules ########################

[/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules]
# PCI device 0x10ec:0x8168 (r8169)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="<MAC 'eth0' [IF]>", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth0"
# PCI device 0x10ec:0x8723 (rtl8723ae)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="<MAC 'wlan0' [IF]>", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="wlan*", NAME="wlan0"

##### dmesg #############################

[    9.169518] rtl8723ae: Using firmware rtlwifi/rtl8723fw_B.bin
[    9.180638] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'rtl_rc'
[    9.180942] rtlwifi: rtlwifi: wireless switch is on
[   10.747446] r8169 0000:04:00.2 eth0: link down (repeated 2 times)
[   12.301950] r8169 0000:04:00.2 eth0: link up
[   18.607023] device virbr0-nic entered promiscuous mode
[   18.721281] virbr0: port 1(virbr0-nic) entered listening state (repeated 2 times)
[   18.728241] virbr0: port 1(virbr0-nic) entered disabled state

########## wireless info END ############
```

Answer (score 0):

Run in terminal

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:hanipouspilot/rtlwifi
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install rtlwifi-new-dkms linux-firmware
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I prefer do not include non official repositories by the security risks. Is there any way to set the device working without include this new repository?

Comment: This is my repository ;-) If you are afraid, you can install the driver and then disable updates from it.

Comment: Nothing personal, I will try everything else first. Drivers are a common way of   attacking, no matter what OS is.

Comment: You can install the same driver form github. But it is the same.